# how to implementation Bluetooth OOB pairing in Android without NFC?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Our android is not support NFC , and we want to OOB, but createBondOutOfBand is a private function, why , why not public the function?  This make it impossible to play OOB without NFC in android . any idea to solve it?  although we can call it by reflection,but Android 9 introduces new restrictions on the use of non-SDK interfaces.thanks

Comment: Connect through USB serial ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler, thanks,do you means adding a usb serial NFC ？ but we can't do so beacause our gatt server isnot a phone ,not a computer, it can't add   usb serial NFC,  it can provide OOB,  the gatt client is a android phone ,although it can add usb serial NFC,but the gatt server doesn't support NFC. so i try to make android support OOB without NFC .

Comment: I am also interested in this topic ...I have custom access to OOB key (without NFC), but I have not found good example how to use Ble OOB pairing in Android, can somebody share a link to article ?